# Getting "Session Expired" message for the active UI

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, vaadin7

Our Java 8 and Spring-based application is generating bulk reports (PDF files) in the background. This might take more than one to two hours. The progress as a percentage value has been updated in the UI (front end) after generating each report, so the UI is active till completing the reports generation, but for some reason we're getting ***Session Expired*** messages in the UI from Vaadin framework in the middle of the report generation process.

Vaadin framework version : 7.6.2
Web Server : Tomcat 7
Value for heartbeat duration : default value (no explicit value configured)
Value for session timeout duration in web.xml : 30 min by default
No change for the value for closeIdleSessions (By default   closeIdleSessions=false)

Can anyone please help to find the reason?

[image: Session Expired]

Comment: What is the transport mode used with Push? Do you have a proxy in front, what is connection time out for that?

Comment: @Tatu Lund There is no explicit value for Push configuration, I think by default it is Automatic. Application is deployed in the Azure App Service.

Comment: If you have just Push without value, the default is WebSocket, see the answer by Leif.

Answer (score 2):

If the only activity is through pushing out status updates through the `@Push` websocket, then that might not be enough to postpone session expiration on the servlet level.

You could work around this by ensuring there is a normal request from the client every now and then just to reset the session timeout. This can be done by enabling UI polling with a long interval, e.g. `ui.setPollInterval((int) Duration.ofMinutes(25).toMillis());`.

Remember to disable the polling after the long task is done, or it will continue to keep your session alive.